# Magento 2.1.8: How to get product final price and regular price

Tags: magento-2.1.7

Below is my product collection code:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addMinimalPrice();
$productCollection->addFinalPrice();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status',
                      array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',
                      array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE));
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                        'visibility', array('in' =>
                                array(
                                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                                )
                             )
                    );
        if ($productCollection->count())
        {
         foreach ($productCollection as $product)
          {
            echo $product->getFinalPrice();
            echo $product->getPrice();
          }
        }
```

Both price gives same amount.It should give product original price and special price.
Please advise me for if I have missed something in code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
$final_price = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();
```

and

```
$regular_price = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
```

also make sure that promotion and taxation is getting applicable on the product into consideration. In case they are not applied, both these prices would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

update your code as below and try

```
    $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(*);
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status',
                          array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',
                          array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE));
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
                            'visibility', array('in' =>
                                    array(
                                        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                                        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                                    )
                                 )
                        );
            if ($productCollection->count())
            {
             foreach ($productCollection as $product)
              {
                echo $product->getFinalPrice();
                echo $product->getPrice();
              }
            }
```